# Extended methods on Boolean value class wrapper

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, value-class

In my codebase I used tags to encode some information into types. As tags works using `t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]` I could get away with many troubles with writing mapping between wrapped and unwrapped values.

Recently I hit the wall with tagged types as they break some functionality in shapeless that I would like to use, so I am trying to use value classes.

So far I could cheat away some e.g. boolean checks with tagged types using something like:

```
implicit class TaggedBooleanAsFirstOperand[P1, U](val c: Rep[P1 @@ U]) {
    private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c.asInstanceOf[Rep[P1]])
    type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

    def @&&[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b)
    def @||[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b)
    def unary_! : Rep[P1] = em.unary_!
  }

  implicit class TaggedBooleanAsSecondOperand[P1](val c: Rep[P1]) {
    private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c)
    type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

    def &&@[P2, U, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ U])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b.asInstanceOf[Rep[P2]])
    def ||@[P2, U, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ U])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b.asInstanceOf[Rep[P2]])
  }

  implicit class TaggedBooleanAsBothOperands[P1, U](val c: Rep[P1 @@ U]) {
    private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c.asInstanceOf[Rep[P1]])
    type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

    def @&&@[P2, V, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ V])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b.asInstanceOf[Rep[P2]])
    def @||@[P2, V, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ V])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b.asInstanceOf[Rep[P2]])
  }
```

With `AnyVal` however, I cannot simply cast one type into the other where I want to, and I would have to provide some honest code allowing to achieve what I want.

I tried to read Slick source code, but the whole idea where should I start is a little blurry to me - relevant information are spread across many places, so I cannot simply pinpoint a few places to e.g. figure how to map one `Rep` into the other or extract data from wrapped and unwrapped Boolean and combine them.

Can some Slick experts recommend some good starting point for those?

Answer (score 0):

Tags actually give you not only type safety. It gives you abstraction level as well. Once you wrapped your `boolean` into a `tag` you abstract away from runtime representation of your boolean. BTW you should use `Tag.unwrap` or `Tag.unsubst` instead of `asInstanceOf`.
Slick works on a lower level of abstraction. It works with simple types which SQL is aware of. 
Of course you need to `unwrap` tags somewhere in between before working with DB. 
I would encapsulate it in table schema. See Mapped Tables section: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html